# How get last day of the month

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a very basic question, I want to get the last day of the month.
This is my query :

```
u.time > date_trunc('year', now()) + i * interval '1  month' and  u.time <date_trunc('year', now()) + i * interval '2  month' -  interval '1  day'
```

Actually, I want set condition only for one month like example, `1/1/20019 - 1/31/2019` and my problem is because the first condition is returned `1/1/2019` and second 12/31/2018 and I want to return `1/31/2019` and reason is because i is 0 on the first time, when is `i=1` everything work good.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you need  below

```
SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f1b637f51214a08d6103f97e22e39ed0)

Comment: I using on this way : `select last_day(to_date(date_trunc('year', now()),'YYYYMMDD'))` and I have error:
`pq: function to_date(timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: I know that but I change time dynamically dependency of i. And the problem is when i is 0 and I'm looking for another solution.